# Ломается приложение при клике по элементу списка

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity

При клике по элементу списка ломается приложение. В отладочном выводе Android Studio написанно следующее

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.hfad.workout, PID: 1959
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hfad.workout/com.hfad.workout.DetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

В чём здесь проблема и как её решить?

Вот код `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.hfad.workout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   WorkoutListFragment.WorkoutListListerer {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void itemClicked(long id){
    View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if(fragmentContainer != null) {
        WorkoutDetailFragment details = new WorkoutDetailFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        details.setWorkout(id);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, details);//замена фрагмента
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    } else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUT_ID,(int)id);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Макет `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_frag"
    class="com.hfad.workout.WorkoutListFragment" />
```

Код `DetailActivity.java`

```
package com.hfad.workout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_WORKOUT_ID="id";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    WorkoutDetailFragment workoutDetailFragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
    long workoutId = (long) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_WORKOUT_ID);
    workoutDetailFragment.setWorkout(workoutId);
}
}
```

Макет `activity_detail.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hfad.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment"
    android:id="@+id/detail_frag"/>
```

Файл WorkoutListFragment.java

```
package com.hfad.workout;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ListView;
```

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {

```
static interface WorkoutListListerer{
    void itemClicked(long id);
};

private WorkoutListListerer listener;


public WorkoutListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] names = new String[Workout.workouts.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.listener = (WorkoutListListerer) activity;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    if(listener !=null){
        listener.itemClicked(id);
    }
}
```

}

Макет fragment_stopwatch.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hfad.workout.StopwatchFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="92sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time_view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/stop"
    android:layout_below="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stop_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Макет fragment_workout_detail

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.hfad.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textTitle" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textDescription"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/stop_watch_container">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: А где у вас в `activity_main.xml` `R.id.fragment_container`? Какой список (откуда `itemClicked`)? Ну и импортируйте нормально `FragmentTransaction`, а то он у вас в строчке `ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)` он не support. Может быть еще где-то.

Comment: У меня есть ещё один activity_main.xml для устройств с большим экраном. Он содержит R.id.fragment_container. itemClicked - это метод моего интерфейса WorkoutListListerer. Он находится в файле WorkoutListFragment.java

Comment: У вас в `detail_frag` не указан `class`, а только `tools:context`. Если дело не в этом, посмотрите по логам, в какой строчке у вас ошибка.

Comment: Я так понимаю это указание на строку с ошибкой?  at com.hfad.workout.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:13)  Это было в описании FATAL EXCEPTION

Comment: Это строчка `setContentView`, значит с активностью все нормально. Дело в xml или в классе фрагмента. А `class` то вместо `tools:context` добавили.

Comment: class="com.hfad.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment" Вы имеете ввиду так? Так не работает

Comment: в activity_main работает, а тут нет?

Comment: Со строкой setContentView всё нормально. Вы правильно сказали, но появилась ещё одна проблема. Приложение ломается и в логе выдаётся следующее   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hfad.workout/com.hfad.workout.DetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0077 (com.hfad.workout:id/fragment_container) for fragment StopwatchFragment{9d085670 #0 id=0x7f0b0077}

Comment: StopwatchFragment это вложенный фрагмент в WorkoutDetailFragment

Comment: Видимо в xml фрагмента его нет... Надо xml смотреть

Comment: выложил xml фрагментов

Comment: И где у вас в `fragment_workout_detail` `StopWatchFragment`? Где строчка в которой он вызывается в классе фрагмента? Много вопросов, много непонятного. Поразбирайтесь сами, посмотрите строчку, где появляется ошибка. Хорошо, что ваш изначально заданный вопрос разрешился. Если возник еще один - задайте его отдельно. Здесь уже слишком много "левого" кода.